# How to dismiss an open dropdown in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a dropdown on my screen, which I want to close every time the user minimises the app (Pause State). I looked into the DropDownButton widget, and it seems it uses Navigator.push() method, so ideally it should be dismissed with Navigator.pop(), if I'm not wrong.

Here is what I've tried already -

1. Use global key to get the context of dropdown widget and implement `Navigator.pop(key.currentContext)` inside `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` function.
2. Use focusNode to implement `.unfocus()` to remove the focus from the dropdown.
3. Maintain a `isDropdownDialogOpen` boolean which I set to `true` on `onTap()` and `false` on `onChange()`. And then simple `pop()` if its `true` on app minimisation. But this approach fails when the user opens the dropdown and then closes it by tapping outside the dropdown dialog. I can't set the boolean to `false` in that case.

My requirement is that - I've to dismiss the dropdown whenever the user minimises the app, if it was open in the first place.

I've gone through bunch of SO questions and GitHub comments, that are even remotely similar, but couldn't find anything helpful.

**Loose Code -**

```dart
class Auth extends State<Authentication> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

    bool isDropdownOpen = false;
    GlobalKey _dropdownKey = GlobalKey();
    FocusNode _focusNode;

    @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  // To pop the open dropdown dialog whenever app is minimised (and opened back on again)
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        if(isDropdownOpen)
          pop();
          // Also tried pop(_dropdownKey.currentContext)
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
    }
  }


  build() {
    return Scaffold(
      // Dummy Dropdown button with random values
      body: DropdownButton(
        key: _dropdownKey,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        value: "one",
        items: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
        //boolean values changing fine, but when user taps outside the dropdown dialog, dropdown is closed and neither of onChanged() and onTap() is called. Need a call back (or something similar) for this particular case.
        onChange(value) => isDropdownOpen = false;
        onTap() => isDropdownOpen = ! isDropdownOpen;
      )
    );
  }

}
```

For your ref - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87989

Comment: can you add your code snippet?

Comment: I've updated the description @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  AppLifecycleState currentAppLifecycleState;
  bool isDropdownMenuShown = false;

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(
      () => currentAppLifecycleState = state,
    );
  }

  String value;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (<AppLifecycleState>[
            AppLifecycleState.inactive,
            AppLifecycleState.detached,
            AppLifecycleState.paused,
          ].contains(currentAppLifecycleState) &&
          isDropdownMenuShown) {
        print('Closing dropdown');
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onLongPressStart: (LongPressStartDetails details) async {
            final left = details.globalPosition.dx;
            final top = details.globalPosition.dy;

            setState(() => isDropdownMenuShown = true);
            final value = await showMenu<String>(
              context: context,
              position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, left, top),
              items: <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: const Text('Option 1'),
                  value: 'Option 1',
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: const Text('Option 2'),
                  value: 'Option 2',
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: const Text('Option 3'),
                  value: 'Option 3',
                ),
              ],
            );

            setState(() => isDropdownMenuShown = false);

            if (value == null) return;

            print('You chose: $value');
          },
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Long press to show dropdown',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How does it work?

We keep track of the current app state using the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method.

Whenever the dropdown is shown the `isDropdownMenuShown` variable is set to `true`.
Whenever the dropdown is closed/exited the variable is set to `false`.

We add a post frame callback (it is called after each rebuild) and we check if the app went into background and if the dropdown is shown. If yes, the dropdown is closed.

Comment: No..I cannot use PopupMenu

Comment: You can make it look like a dropdown.

Comment: I can..but that doesn't help my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way to programmatically close an open drop-down list in Flutter:

1. In the State declarations, define a global key like this:

```
    class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
        final dropdownState = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
```

2. In the drop-down widget, assign this key, like this:

```
   child: DropdownButtonFormField(
       key: dropdownState,
```

3. When you want to close the open drop-down from anywhere in your code, place this line of code:

```
    Navigator.pop(dropdownState.currentContext!); // Close the dropdown list
```